# Integrate jquery code with CKeditor

Tags: jquery, laravel, ckeditor

I need transform my code that will work with CKeditor 
[example code](http://jsfiddle.net/a9Lyybef/30/)

```
$("#reply").click(function () {
$("#message-text").val("[\quote]" + document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML + "[\/quote]\n").show();});
```

*var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'message-text' )*

Comment: Please read [ask] and update question so that it is complete and clear about what the exact problem is as well as include all relevant code in question itself. Your demo has nothing to do with CKeditor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to set CKEditor text?

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances['message-text'];
editor.setData('Your string or HTML');
```

OR

```
CKEDITOR.instances['message-text'].setData('Your string ')
```